# Command-line dependency tree for BitBake recipes

Tags: yocto, bitbake

For some reason, my Yocto image build is pulling in xserver-xorg along with several other GUI-related dependencies such as GTK3+ and Wayland. I want to understand where this dependency is being declared, but there doesn't seem to be an easy mechanism to do this with BitBake. Things I have tried so far:

- Starting the Toaster server, so that I can search and navigate recipes a little easier - for some reason, I get connection refused when trying to access the page. Perhaps it's down to firewall... - at the end of the day, I don't really want a bulky webserver for this.
- I tried `bitbake -g xserver-xorg -u ncurses`, but this just gave me ncurses showing that it has written a `.dot` file...
- I tried rendering the `.dot` file into something useful with Graphviz, but it is so massive it is of no help.

All I want is to say "Hey BitBake, give me the recipes which have a direct dependence on package X, and that are active in this image, please."

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a cheat but if you "break" the dependency you want to remove, e.g. remove the recipe, it will then tell you what is depending upon it.